# ggplot facet_wrap - removing columns and rows with no data OR alternatives when you don't have all data combinations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to map species abundance on a bubble curve with two sites over two years. I am using facet_wrap to divide the plots into years by column and taxonomic family by row. However, as not all data combinations are present the result is duplicating rows and columns with no data (see below). For example, species are duplicated into families where they do not belong and all samples are included on the x-axis instead of only showing the relevant year.

How can I remove these redundant rows and columns? I've tried scale = Free and Drop = True but these only work on whole plots that are empty. I know facet-wrap is supposed to be used when you have all combinations of data but I cannot find another alternative.

Many Thanks

```
        ggplot(data2, aes(x=Sample, y=Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=ifelse(Value==0, NA, Value), alpha = 0.75)) +
  scale_size(range = c(0, 5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels= xlabels, 
                   limits=c("Developed_zone_1992","Paddock_zone_1992",
                            "Sanctuary_zone_1992", "Developed_zone_2020",
                            "Paddock_zone_2020", "Sanctuary_zone_2020")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=7)) +
  facet_grid(Family ~ Year)
```

Sample data is below, pasted from my dput file (I couldn't find how to upload this separately, if there is a better way please let me know.

```
structure(list(Year = c("1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989"), Sample = c("Developed_zone_1992", 
"Developed_zone_2020", "Paddock_zone_1992", "Paddock_zone_2020", 
"Sanctuary_zone_1992", "Sanctuary_zone_2020", "Developed_zone_1992", 
"Developed_zone_2020", "Paddock_zone_1992", "Paddock_zone_2020", 
"Sanctuary_zone_1992", "Sanctuary_zone_2020", "Developed_zone_1992", 
"Developed_zone_2020", "Paddock_zone_1992", "Paddock_zone_2020", 
"Sanctuary_zone_1992", "Sanctuary_zone_2020", "Developed_zone_1992", 
"Developed_zone_2020", "Paddock_zone_1992", "Paddock_zone_2020", 
"Sanctuary_zone_1992", "Sanctuary_zone_2020", "Developed_zone_1992"
), Value = c(2L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 10L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 10L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L), Family = c("Phasianidae", 
"Phasianidae", "Phasianidae", "Phasianidae", "Phasianidae", "Phasianidae", 
"Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", 
"Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", 
"Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", "Anatidae", 
"Anatidae"), Species = c("1. Grey francolin (60)", "1. Grey francolin (60)", 
"1. Grey francolin (60)", "1. Grey francolin (60)", "1. Grey francolin (60)", 
"1. Grey francolin (60)", "2. Egyptian goose (55)", "2. Egyptian goose (55)", 
"2. Egyptian goose (55)", "2. Egyptian goose (55)", "2. Egyptian goose (55)", 
"2. Egyptian goose (55)", "3. Garganey (60)", "3. Garganey (60)", 
"3. Garganey (60)", "3. Garganey (60)", "3. Garganey (60)", "3. Garganey (60)", 
"4. Northern shoveler (62)", "4. Northern shoveler (62)", "4. Northern shoveler (62)", 
"4. Northern shoveler (62)", "4. Northern shoveler (62)", "4. Northern shoveler (62)", 
"5. Mallard (67)")), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXkwm.png)

Comment: Clean data beforehand with `data2[data2 == 0] <- NA;data2 <- data2[complete.cases(data2), ]` then try again?

Answer (score 2):

You couldn't get the free x-axes because you hardcoded the limits in `scale_x_discrete()`. I recommend using factor levels to order them. For the y-axis I didn't have any problems dropping them with `facet_grid(..., scales = "free")`.

Also I would filter out the cases where `Value == 0`, just so the scales don't mistakenly think there are datapoints there.

Assuming your data.frame is called `df`:

```
df$Sample <- factor(df$Sample,
                    levels = c("Developed_zone_1992","Paddock_zone_1992",
                               "Sanctuary_zone_1992", "Developed_zone_2020",
                               "Paddock_zone_2020", "Sanctuary_zone_2020"))

ggplot(df[df$Value != 0,], aes(x=Sample, y=Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=Value, alpha = 0.75)) +
  scale_size(range = c(0, 5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=7)) +
  facet_grid(Family ~ Year, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: That works great, thanks! I played around with the scale_x_discrete but couldn't get the right result. The only thing now is that the y-axis is in a random order (I had encoded the order using a number column in the df and scale_y_discrete). Do you know how I can conserve the y-axis to retain the taxonomic order (ie by family?). Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yeah sure, you can do a similar tricks as with the x-axis: you just encode your y-variable as a factor of which the levels are in the desired order.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately on my whole dataset the family labels are not readable. Instead of splitting the plot by family I'll look for an alternative, like adding family name to the y-axis or having a dividing line between them on the plot.